# function runs though header is not included

Tags: c, include

consider the following code, which causes a weird behavior:

### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo();

#endif
```

### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// NOTICE - foo.h is not included!

void foo()
{
    printf("foo!\n");
}
```

### main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

running this code I get in the console: `foo!`

what bugs me here is that I expected that `main.c` would not be familiar with the implementation of `foo()`, since `foo.h` is not included in `foo.c`, and hence `foo()` should be an inner function in `foo.c`. It happened to me both when I ran it in VS2010 and when I compiled an exe using gcc (on windows).
can someone explain this phenomenon? I thought about it and I have no idea why it happens. thanks.

Comment: Foo does not need to know about itself to get compiled.

Comment: `main` __is__ not familiar with the implementation of `foo.h`. `main` is familiar with the _definition_ of `foo`. Therefore the compiler can generate the code to call `foo` and the linker eventually kind of "sticks" it all together.

Comment: BTW you _should_ include `foo.h` in `foo.c`, even if this is not required, but it may help to prevent errors.

Comment: What happens if I implement `foo` differently in another header file (e.g `bar.h`)? I get a linkage error?

Comment: That's one of the frequent causes for the [LNK2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) (when using the Microsoft linker, obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header file is declaring the function, so when compiling main.c the compiler knows the function signature to validate against. When compiling foo.c, it doesn't need to be declared, as it is the declaration of the function. It is up to the linker to see if there are any unresolved symbols, which there aren't in this case, so all is good, and also why you're seeing this work.

Comment: What is a "pre-declaration"? The standard only knows declarations. And C does not support _methods_. Your usage of terms is very confusing. Please use standard terms correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if there was another function(test.c) included in the above question.

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo();

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
// NOTICE - foo.h is not included!

void foo()
{
    printf("foo!\n");
}
```

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>  
void foo()
{
    printf("foo!\n");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is that a question? if it is, it was answered in the comments of the main question - there will be a linking error because the linker does not know which `foo` is the relevant one...

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I would think that is bad practice not to include the header. But when exposing the header you expose all the functions and variables to the the file that you are including it in. There is no partial exposure. That's my gripe...